# Ruby how to get a date to the default format as it's stored in the db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, datetime, datetime-format

My db is by default storing times as such:

```
Object.last.created_at
# => Fri, 03 Jul 2015 23:27:50 UTC +00:00
```

I looked at the `strftime` docs and I can build that myself, but it seems there must be an easy way to get a regular Date object to that format? Just wondering if there is...

`to_datetime` gets really close, but not exactly all the way there.

Date.today.to_datetime
   # => Sat, 04 Jul 2015 00:00:00 +0000

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh silly me... it's just

```
Date.today.in_time_zone
# => Mon, 06 Jul 2015 00:00:00 UTC +00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Time.zone.now
#=> Sat, 04 Jul 2015 20:32:44 UTC +00:00
```

**UPDATE**

```
DateTime.now.in_time_zone
#=> Sat, 04 Jul 2015 20:43:57 UTC +00:00
```

Comment: Sorry should be more specific, I need to work with any Date object